# Proper filter usage within the Google Analytics embed API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I'm using the google analytics embed API to show data in console. All works well till i add a filter to the query.

I want to not include pages what have `Movie.aspx` in it.

Is it not supported by the API or is my syntax incorrect?

```
 var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
                query: {
                    metrics: 'ga:pageviewsPerSession',
                    dimensions: 'ga:pagePath',
                    sort: '-ga:pageviewsPerSession',
                   //doesn't work when i add this line
                   // 'filters':'ga:pageviewsPerSession!@Movie.aspx', 
                    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                    'end-date': 'yesterday',
                     'max-results': 10
                },
                chart: {
                    container: 'chart-5-container',
                    type: 'TABLE'
                }
            });
```

Edit:
Also i can't seem to get the chart to format correctly.

Each column returns 00,01,02,03 etc.
I'm trying to format it to display 02:00 AM

```
 var dataChart3 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                dimensions: 'ga:hour',
                'start-date': '1daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday'
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'chart-7-container',
                type: 'COLUMN',
                options: {
                    width: '100%',
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Time of Day',
                        format: 'hh:mm a'
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Number of sessions'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Update 24/05/2017
Thanks I've manged to sort it out using the below query

```
     var PageListConfig = {
            query: {
                //metrics: 'ga:sessions,ga:avgPageLoadTime',
                metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                dimensions: 'ga:pagePath',
                filters: 'ga:pagePath!@Movie;ga:pagePath!@SessionTimesDisplay;ga:pagePath!@SessionTimesDaySelect;ga:pagePath!@VenueTicketing',
                sort: '-ga:sessions',
                'max-results': 30
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'chart-5-container',
                type: 'TABLE'
            }
        };
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

> ga:pageviewsPerSession
>
> The average number of pages viewed during a session, including repeated views of a single page.

The above metadata is a metric not a dimension which means you need to use one of the metric filter operators also its a number you cant compare a number to a string

You may want to consider one of the page path dimensions.

> ga:pagePath=@Movie.aspx

check out the [filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) syntax documentation on the Google Analytics developer site.  I also recommend testing them out in the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)